# Does linq block the thread?

Tags: .net, linq, concurrency

I am turning some stored procedure to vb.net linq (SQL to linq .... manually) because stored procedure is slow.

I am using linq queries in concurrent threads.

After running a performance analyzing, I find out the linq seems to lock the source collection(like cache.IPMS_TBL_EL_PRICE_COMPONENT in the code period below) when querying.

Is it true? Is there a (not_lock/lock) option for linq?
I really don't want the collection to be locked. It will slow the multi-thread query.

Thank you very much.

Code period:

see in https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLlI6.jpg or see below

```
insert0 = (From PPC In cache.IPMS_TBL_EL_PRODUCT_PRICE_COMPONENT_MAPPING
                           From PC In cache.IPMS_TBL_EL_PRICE_COMPONENT
                           Join LK In cache.IPMS_TBL_LOOKUP
                             On PC.Component_Type_Id Equals LK.Lookup_Id
                           Where (PC.Component_Id = PPC.Component_Id OrElse PC.Component_Type_Id = CC3_ID) _
                             AndAlso LK.Commodity_Id = ELE_COMMODITY_ID _
                             AndAlso LK.Lookup_Type.ToLower = PRICE_COMPONENT_TYPE.ToLower _
                             AndAlso PPC.Product_Id = IN_PRODUCT_ID _
                             AndAlso PPC.Price_Type_Id = IN_PRICE_TYPE_ID _
                             AndAlso PC.Is_Deleted = 0 _
                             AndAlso LK.Lookup_Id > MINUS_HUNDRED _
                             AndAlso PC.Component_Id > MINUS_HUNDRED _
                             AndAlso lookupValues.Contains(LK.Lookup_Value.ToLower) _
                             AndAlso (Not PC.ISO_Id.HasValue OrElse Not deletedISO.Contains(PC.ISO_Id.Value))
                           Select New PriceComponents() With {.ComponentID = PC.Component_Id,
                                                              .ComponentName = PC.Component_Name,
                                                              .ComponentTypeID = PC.Component_Type_Id,
                                                              .ComponentTypeName = LK.Lookup_Value,
                                                              .Sequence = PC.Sequence,
                                                              .OrderSequence = orderSequeceDict(LK.Lookup_Value.ToLower),
                                                              .IsMTM = PC.Is_MTM,
                                                              .UcapUsageFactorUnitPrice = PC.UCAP_Usage_Factor_UnitPrice,
                                                              .Percentage = PERCENTAGE}
                           ).OrderBy(Function(e As PriceComponents) e.OrderSequence).ThenBy(Function(e As PriceComponents) e.Sequence) _
                           .Distinct(New PriceComponentsComparer_PK_9_Fields).ToList
```

Comment: If `cache` is a LINQ to SQL data context then it should not be shared across threads.

Comment: Let's back up a bit here...  Did you figure out why the stored procedure was slow?  That's an unusual reason to convert to L2S.  Does the LINQ query out perform your stored procedure?

Comment: Is the question about blocking (non-deferred, synchronous execution) or about what gets locked (preventing multithreaded use) during the query? These are very different things.

Comment: @PeteM yeah. The stored procedure is f**king slow. It will join 3 or 4 hundred-million-record table together and spend 10 min to run.Some f**king company named Cognizant wrote it and put in a three-layered loop. The new linq substitution only takes 2 second.

Comment: @jdv-JandeVaan:  It's about trying not be blocking by linq.

Comment: I would look at writing your own stored procedure if possible, assuming that's the usual method for data access within your application.  Next question... what do you mean by "multi threaded query"?  L2S is not generally thread safe.  As @JonathanAllen mentions, it is very bad to try to hit the same context at the same time from multiple threads.  You might have to take a very different approach depending on what you're trying to do and why.

Comment: @PeteM: Well,the stored procedures I got is slow because it takes long time to join very fat tables (several hundred million records). I am running the linq query in parallel.for loop, and I don't modify the source (e.g. cache.IPMS_TBL_EL_PRICE_COMPONENT), so it shouldn't have concurrency issue. Therefore, I don't need a lock. But the linq  join operations seem to lock the source automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `ToList` which causes the query to evaluate eagerly (there and then).

With `ToList`, it will iterate over the result set returning the requested results - this will indeed use the current thread.

You can *defer* evaluation by not calling `ToList` and only evaluate when you actually need to iterate over the results.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I will set up a simple project to test this approach. waiting another hour for more answers. Thank you.